# C# .NET equivalent to PHP time()

Tags: c#, php

I am working with C# .NET and PHP and need some standard way of recording time between the two. I want to use seconds since 1970 = `<?php echo time(); ?>` because I'm already using some of php's cool functions like: date() & strtotime() in my project. Is there something in .net that is equivalent to PHP time()?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
(int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way :

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear *why* you need an equivalent for PHP `time()`, but you can do:

```
var secondsSinceUnixEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow
                                    .Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))
                                    .TotalSeconds;

// If needed.
var roundedSeconds = (int) secondsSinceUnixEpoch;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as simple as that:

```
var secondsSince1970 = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("01.01.1970 00:00:00");
Debug.Write(secondsSince1970.TotalSeconds.ToString());
```

Comment: @PatrickLorio: You're right. I took a wrong property. I've corrected the sample.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure (datatype) - It  represents a date and time. You can use [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) and [DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) (Coordinated UTC)  property to get local time.

To get time interval you can use [Timespan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure.